# Rails update_all dependent model crashed the webserver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I want to update all dependent `Schedule` records using `update_all` every time I update a `Klass` record.

```
Activity
  has_many :schedules
Klass
  belongs_to :activity
  has_many   :schedules
Schedule
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :klass
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :partner

# Schedule attributes
klass_id
activity_id

# Klass form
<%= f.label :activity_id, "Category" %><br>
<%= collection_select(:klass, :activity_id, Activity.order(:name), :id, :name) %>

# KlassesController
def update
  @partner = Partner.find(params[:partner_id])
  @klass   = @partner.klasses.find(params[:id])

  if @klass.update(klass_params)
    Schedule.where(klass_id: @klass.id).update_all(activity_id: klass_params[:activity_id])
    redirect_to ...
  else
    ...
  end
end

private

def klass_params
  params.require(:klass).permit(:name, :activity_id, :level,
                                :age_start, :age_end, :description)
end
```

But the problem is `update_all` command crashed the webserver (Webrick). The webserver just... hangs. I tried restarting Webrick but the problem is repeatable.

**Bonus:** The weird thing is when I tried `update_all` on `Schedule` every time I update the `City` attribute on `Partner`, the webserver did crashed once. But after I restarted Webrick it works without any problem.

```
# PartnersController
def update
  @partner = Partner.find(params[:id])
  if @partner.update(partner_params)
    Schedule.where(partner_id: @partner.id).update_all(city_id: @partner.city_id)
    redirect_to ...
  else
    ...
  end
end

City
  has_many :schedules
Partner
  belongs_to :city
  has_many :klasses
  has_many :schedules
```

**My question is:** Is there any other way to update dependent records without using `update_all`? Or `update_all` is the right way but the webserver is the issue? Or I'm doing it all wrong?

Comment: What database are you using? Does the SQL command lock up for some reason?  You could have a huge table that is taking forever to update.

Comment: @tadman I'm using Postgres. There are only 13 records inside `Schedule` table.

Comment: @tadman How do I see if the SQL command lock up? I run the command in `rails console` with no problem. In the server logs it hangs at `COMMIT` after updating the `Klass` record. The `Klass` record did get updated but not the dependent `Schedule` records.

Comment: That same `update_all` code runs fine in the console?

Comment: @diego.greyrobot Yes.

Comment: It depends on what database you're using, which is why I asked. For example, on MySQL the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` will give you a list of what queries are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Webrick crashed because I have the `rails console` running in another terminal tab. Exiting the console and restarting Webrick solves this problem.

But I'm still curious if there's another way to mass update the dependent records without using `update_all`.

**edit:**
As Tadman's suggestion, I've simplified the query for `update_all`:

```
# KlassesController
@klass.schedules.update_all(activity_id: klass_params[:activity_id])

# PartnersController
@partner.schedules.update_all(city_id: @partner.city_id)
```

Comment: It's the best tool for the job. Why are you opposed to using it?

Comment: I was thinking if it's better to do mass update in the model or something rather than the controller. But if you say so...

Comment: It's a subjective call in this case. If you think that update is a meaningful operation that will be done in more than one location, you'd make a class method in the appropriate model that can accommodate it. You might want to rework this to read: `@partner.schedules.update_all(...)` if you have your relationships established properly.